# Calling WCF using Proxy

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services

I am consuming a WCF service whose wsdl is not published on the website. The developers of the service have since given me wsdl file to generate the proxy class from it.

I have successfully successfully generated the file using VS2010 svcutil.exe command. I included the file in the project I am working on, however, when calling for the webservice, there is no request going to the webservice host from the proxy class as evidenced by a third party packet sniffer that I used to check outgoing request and responses.

I am just sending through static information

I am new to WCF service so please advise if there is a part I need to add.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Web.UI.Page
Imports System.Math 
Public Class webservicetest
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim Song As New request
    Try
        Song.songname() = "TakeMeHome"
        Song.trackNumber() = Convert.ToInt32("1")
        Song.requestNumber() = Convert.ToInt32("5689")
        Song.language() = "english"
        Song.albumtitle() = "GetMeThere"
        Song.totalAlbums() = Convert.ToDecimal("35")

        Dim songresponse As New responce

        Label1.Text = songresponse.errorMessage()
        Label2.Text = songresponse.requestDateTime()
        Label3.Text = songresponse.requestNumber()
        Label4.Text = songresponse.status()
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub

End Class
```

part of the app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Songinformation" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="urlWherewebserviceIsDeployed"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Songinformation"
            contract="Songdata" name="BasicHttpBinding_Songdata" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

part of the proxy class

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
<Assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute("http://ucizi.music/DataContracts", ClrNamespace:="ucizi.music.DataContracts")>

Namespace ucizi.music.DataContracts

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
     System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0"), _
     System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name:="Request", [Namespace]:="http://ucizi.Music/DataContracts")> _
    Partial Public Class Request
    Inherits Object
    Implements System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    Private extensionDataField As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject

    Private albumtitle As String

    Private songname As String

    Private trackNumber As Integer

    Private language As String

    Private requestNumber As UInteger

    Private totalAlbums As Integer


    Public Property ExtensionData() As       System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject Implements      System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData
        Get
            Return Me.extensionDataField
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject)
            Me.extensionDataField = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired:=True)> _
    Public Property albumtitle() As String
        Get
            Return Me.albumtitlebox
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.albumtitlebox = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired:=True, Order:=2)> _
    Public Property songname() As String
        Get
            Return Me.songnamebox
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.songnamebox = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired:=True, Order:=3)> _
    Public Property tracknumber() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.tracknumberbox
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me.tracknumberbox = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired:=True, Order:=4)> _
    Public Property language() As String
        Get
            Return Me.languagebox
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Me.languagebox = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired:=True, Order:=5)> _
    Public Property requestnumber() As UInteger
        Get
            Return Me.requestnumberbox
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As UInteger)
            Me.requestnumberbox = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired:=True, Order:=6)> _
    Public Property totalAlbums() As Integer
        Get
            Return Me.totalAlbumsbox
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me.totalAlbumsbox = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

'rest of codes
End Namespace

<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0"), _
 System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute([Namespace]:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts", ConfigurationName:="MusicServiceContract")> _
Public Interface MusicServiceContract

'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper namespace (http://ucizi.music/MessageContracts) of message SubmitRequest does not match the default value (http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts)
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/SubmitP" & _
    "ayment", ReplyAction:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/SubmitP" & _
    "aymentResponse"), _
  System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(GetType(ucizi.music.DataContracts.GeneralFaultContract), Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/SubmitP" & _
    "aymentGeneralFaultContractFault", Name:="GeneralFaultContract", [Namespace]:="http://ucizi.music/DataContracts")> _
Function SubmitPayment(ByVal request As SubmitRequest) As SubmitPaymentResponse

'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper namespace (http://ucizi.music/MessageContracts) of message SubmitReversalRequest does not match the default value (http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts)
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/SubmitR" & _
    "eversal", ReplyAction:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/SubmitR" & _
    "eversalResponse"), _
  System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(GetType(ucizi.music.DataContracts.GeneralFaultContract), Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/SubmitR" & _
    "eversalGeneralFaultContractFault", Name:="GeneralFaultContract", [Namespace]:="http://ucizi.music/DataContracts")> _
Function SubmitReversal(ByVal request As SubmitReversalRequest) As SubmitReversalResponse

'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper namespace (http://ucizi.music/MessageContracts) of message GetPaymentConfRequest does not match the default value (http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts)
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/Payment" & _
    "Confirmation", ReplyAction:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/Payment" & _
    "ConfirmationResponse"), _
  System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(GetType(ucizi.music.DataContracts.GeneralFaultContract), Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/Payment" & _
    "ConfirmationGeneralFaultContractFault", Name:="GeneralFaultContract", [Namespace]:="http://ucizi.music/DataContracts")> _
Function PaymentConfirmation(ByVal request As GetPaymentConfRequest) As GetPaymentConfResponse

'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper namespace (http://ucizi.music/MessageContracts) of message GetAvailableMOPRequest does not match the default value (http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts)
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/GetAvai" & _
    "lableMethodOfPayments", ReplyAction:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/GetAvai" & _
    "lableMethodOfPaymentsResponse"), _
     System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(GetType(ucizi.music.DataContracts.GeneralFaultContract), Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/GetAvai" & _
    "lableMethodOfPaymentsGeneralFaultContractFault", Name:="GeneralFaultContract", [Namespace]:="http://ucizi.music/DataContracts")> _
Function GetAvailableMethodOfPayments(ByVal request As GetAvailableMOPRequest) As GetAvailableMOPResponse

'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper namespace (http://ucizi.music/MessageContracts) of message GetTransactionHistoryRequest does not match the default value (http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts)
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/GetTran" & _
    "sactionHistory", ReplyAction:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/GetTran" & _
    "sactionHistoryResponse"), _
 System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(GetType(ucizi.music.DataContracts.GeneralFaultContract), Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/GetTran" & _
    "sactionHistoryGeneralFaultContractFault", Name:="GeneralFaultContract", [Namespace]:="http://ucizi.music/DataContracts")> _
Function GetTransactionHistory(ByVal request As GetTransactionHistoryRequest) As GetTransactionHistoryResponse

'CODEGEN: Generating message contract since the wrapper namespace (http://ucizi.music/MessageContracts) of message SubmitSmartCardRequest does not match the default value (http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts)
<System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/SubmitP" & _
    "aymentUsingSmartCard", ReplyAction:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/SubmitP" & _
    "aymentUsingSmartCardResponse"), _
 System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(GetType(ucizi.music.DataContracts.GeneralFaultContract), Action:="http://ucizi.music/ServiceContracts/MusicServiceContract/SubmitP" & _
    "aymentUsingSmartCardGeneralFaultContractFault", Name:="GeneralFaultContract", [Namespace]:="http://ucizi.music/DataContracts")> _
Function SubmitPaymentUsingSmartCard(ByVal request As SubmitSmartCardRequest) As SubmitPaymentResponse
End Interface

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0"), _
  System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced), _
 System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName:="SubmitRequest", WrapperNamespace:="http://ucizi.music/MessageContracts", IsWrapped:=True)> _
    Partial Public Class SubmitRequest

    <System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute([Namespace]:="http://ucizi.music  /ServiceContracts", Order:=0)>   _
   Public Request As ucizi.music.DataContracts.Request

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal Request As ucizi.music.DataContracts.Request)
    MyBase.New()
    Me.Request = Request
End Sub
End Class

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")> _
Partial Public Class MusicServiceContractsClient
Inherits System.ServiceModel.ClientBase(Of MusicServiceContracts)
Implements MusicServiceContracts

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal endpointConfigurationName As String)
    MyBase.New(endpointConfigurationName)
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal endpointConfigurationName As String, ByVal remoteAddress As String)
    MyBase.New(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal endpointConfigurationName As String, ByVal remoteAddress As System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)
    MyBase.New(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal binding As System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding, ByVal remoteAddress As System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress)
    MyBase.New(binding, remoteAddress)
End Sub

<System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)> _
    Function MusicServiceContract_SubmitRequest(ByVal request As SubmitMusicRequest) As SubmitMusicResponse Implements MusicServiceContracts.SubmitMusic
    Return MyBase.Channel.SubmitMusic(request)
End Function

Public Function SubmitMusic(ByVal PaymentRequest As multichoice.paymentservice.DataContracts.PaymentRequest) As multichoice.paymentservice.DataContracts.TransactionResponse
    Dim inValue As SubmitMusicRequest = New SubmitMusicRequest()
    inValue.PaymentRequest = PaymentRequest
    Dim retVal As SubmitMusicResponse = CType(Me, MusicServiceContracts).SubmitMusic(inValue)
    Return retVal.PaymentResponse
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: All I see in your proxy is a DataContract.  I don't see any methods for you to call against the service.  Is this the only code generated by scvutil?

Comment: I also have MusicServiceContract Interface and SubmitRequest class as editted in the code above

Comment: You're not actually calling a method - you're just `new`ing up a response.  You need to make a client and call the service with your request to get the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently just `new`ing up a response.  You need to create a service client and use that to call the service to get your response.

I'm a C# developer, but I imagine something like this:

```
Dim client as New MusicServiceContractsClient
Dim songresponse = client.SubmitMusic(request)
```

Comment: Thanks Zimdanen. so much helpful.